# ServiceStack SharpScript Future

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

I've been using ServiceStack for many years, I currently designing and planning a rewrite of an ASP MVC (Razor) project. #Script seems to be an almost perfect fit, without hands-on experience of the technology I have some doubts and questions.

My question is how relevant is #Script today and what is the future plans of this technology. I ask these questions because when I looked at GitHub example I noticed that there is not a lot of activity, and searching the internet I am also not finding a community around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [#Script](https://sharpscript.net)'s author I would say that `#Script` is a complete library for what it's designed for as an [embeddable sandboxed](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sandbox) .NET scripting and templating language that's ideal for [exploratory programming](https://sharpscript.net/#exploratory-programming) with [seamless integration into .NET APIs](https://sharpscript.net/docs/script-net) (including [Win32 APIs](https://sharpscript.net/sharp-apps/win32)) that includes a vast built-in library (1000+) of [filters](https://sharpscript.net/docs/scripts-reference) that's easily and highly extensible to the point that it's even able to natively support [multiple languages](https://sharpscript.net/docs/syntax#multi-language-support) (inc. [built-in LISP Repl](https://sharpscript.net/lisp/#lisp-repl)) within the same page that's been a joy to develop with thanks to its built-in [Hot Reloading](https://sharpscript.net/docs/hot-reloading) support where changes are instantly visible upon save - so technology-wise IMO it's pretty great.

If we were to compare it to comparable libraries in other languages like the [Ruby's Liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/) it should be pretty clear that `#Script` is vastly more capable where it scales from a user-friendly templating language to a powerful scripting language where it's capable of developing entire [Windows Desktop Apps that fits in a Gist](https://sharpscript.net/sharp-apps/gist-desktop-apps).

On the activity front, Liquid is also an established library with low activity with only a [handful of commits in 2021](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/commits/master), the difference is that it's [vastly more popular](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki#who-uses-liquid) and used in popular products like [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) as used in [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) which ensures it will always have a rich, vibrant ecosystem which is the most important indicator for assessing a technology's longevity.

### Technology not as important as ecosystem

However in the end the technology doesn't matter nearly as much as its user base, community and ecosystem behind it which is where `#Script` is sorely lacking. Unfortunately this is the reality of libraries that compete Microsoft's defaults like Razor which are exclusively promoted for .NET and will always retain the majority of adoption in .NET.

`#Script` is a "complete" library in that I've added all the features I planned for it and there's basically nothing I can think of to add to it to make it more appealing, but facing the realization of its indefinite lack of adoption I wouldn't recommend using it for large living (i.e. multi-year) Websites, given it will never have the community and adoption enjoyed by other ecosystems since the benefits of a community and ecosystem are ultimately the most important attributes in order to continue investing in a technology.

##### Continue to be actively supported

Like all of [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net), `#Script` is still an actively supported library with [no outstanding issues](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues) so it's safe to use in that any issues will be promptly resolved should you wish to.

### Website Development Recommendations

I'd say it's still a fine option for smaller definitively-scoped projects since its compile-time-free and Hot-Reload makes for a very productive Dev UX for server-generated dynamic pages. However even then I'd first evaluate if a static generated framework like [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) or other [popular static generators](https://jamstack.org/generators/) would be more appropriate since they enjoy a vibrant community and a statically generated site results in a more performant, resilient and cheaper to host and deploy website.

#### Static Site Generators

Having recently redeveloped the [servicestack.net](https://servicestack.net) website to split it out into using Jekyll for static content and [ServiceStack.Razor](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-razor) for dynamic content, [my recommendation for large websites](https://twitter.com/demisbellot/status/1393286538570596352) with large static and dynamic components is to use a static site generator for its static content which yields several benefits:

[image]

Although it does require a fair bit of overhead to setup as you're effectively maintaining 2 different websites however it greatly benefits if the static content is actively updated as there's a lot less friction to change and update content on a static generated site then a dynamic one and it results in a superior end user UX thanks to CDN Edge caches that's also cheaper to host from free sites like [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) and [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/).

In order to preserve existing URLs we needed extra functionality not possible from a static host so our static content is deployed to a S3 bucket where we use CloudFront for CDN edge caching, CF Behaviors for proxying "external static" routes to our [.NET5 dynamic website](https://account.servicestack.net/) and a CF Function for supporting pretty URLs. For internally deployed websites you'll be able to accomplish similar functionality with reverse proxy and redirect rules.

#### SPA or Razor

For small websites or mostly dynamic websites that wont benefit from a content site split I'd recommend either an [SPA Project Template](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-single-page-apps) if you prefer TypeScript and an established SPA FX like [Vue](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-vue), [React](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-react), [Svelte](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-svelte) or [Angular](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-angular) or [Razor or MVC](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-websites) if you instead prefer C# server generated websites.

#### Progressive Enhancement

My personal preference is for read-heavy dynamic sites to use ServiceStack Razor utilizing [API First Development](https://docs.servicestack.net/api-first-development) approach so that all writes are made to the same clean ServiceStack APIs that Mobile and Desktop Apps would also call. This typically involves using some kind of progressive enhancement like our [Client TypeScript](https://docs.servicestack.net/world-validation#client-uis-1) Validation example which utilizes the [Form & Validation Binding in @servicestack/client](https://docs.servicestack.net/servicestack-client-umd#bootstrap-forms) to take over `<form>` submissions to perform TypeScript API calls and apply any validation errors back to the Form's UI.

The [Client jQuery](https://docs.servicestack.net/world-validation#client-uis-1) example accomplishes the same thing without the `tsc -w` watched build step whose [form & validation binding](https://docs.servicestack.net/ss-utils-js#bootstrap-forms) utilizes the older jQuery [ss-utils.js library](https://docs.servicestack.net/ss-utils-js) but it does mean you'd need to author logic in an older broadly [ECMAScript 5](https://caniuse.com/?search=es5) supported version of JS.

### Future of `#Script`

As I don't expect [#Script Pages](https://sharpscript.net/docs/script-pages) will ever achieve any meaningful adoption  required for self-sustained active development, it's unlikely we'll continue in investing in further development for usage in dynamic websites (i.e. the [script](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/script) project template), it's a complete and extensible library so further development isn't strictly necessary as it can be easily extended with your own local Plugins, Methods, Transformers and Blocks. But it does mean we're unlikely to be creating and including new methods/plugins designed for dynamic websites in the library OOB.

##### Still a critical ServiceStack component

#Script is still a critical component of ServiceStack where it's used to provide integrated SPA templates since it's able to render dynamic websites from static `*.html` pages in npm dev hot-reload servers which can't use Razor's `*.cshtml` pages. It's also what makes ServiceStack's [Declarative Validation](https://docs.servicestack.net/declarative-validation) possible where validation rules can be defined on dependency-free DTOs as it allows defining binary-decoupled logic in dep-free attributes. It's also what makes [vuedesktop.com](https://www.vuedesktop.com/) Desktop Apps like [ServiceStack Studio](https://docs.servicestack.net/studio) possible as well as command tools like Post Command - [HTTP API Command Line Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/post-command) and [cross-platform dotnet scripts](https://docs.servicestack.net/dotnet-scripts#cross-platform-scripts) which makes usage of its internal functionality, so it's going to continue on as a actively developed & supported library.

#### Good future use-cases of `#Script`

However I'd limit any #Script usage to where it excels, e.g. as an embeddable scripting .NET sandbox given it's more versatile & flexible than Razor for tasks like [Rendering Emails](https://docs.servicestack.net/dotnet-scripts#cross-platform-scripts), authoring & rendering [Live Documents](https://sharpscript.net/usecases/live-documents) (e.g. if needing to maintain live user-generated reports in an RDBMS) or as an embeddable Template, JS or LISP DSL or for evaluating adhoc [JS/LISP Expressions or .NET logic](https://docs.servicestack.net/js-utils).

#### Future replacement project templates

For developing server-generated websites with ServiceStack we're looking at shipping a couple of new templates which encompasses our latest recommendations (e.g. embracing an API First Development style), if they result in a great Dev UX we're looking at:

1. An Integrated Static generated (e.g. Hugo/Jekyll) + Dynamic Project template
2. An API First MVC Pages + ServiceStack template with integrated progressive enhancement

Please follow [@ServiceStack](https://twitter.com/ServiceStack) to get notified as soon as they become available.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. My application is a business application basically a  process flow system (for warehouses), you have a process with x amount of steps, each step execute an API call, but there is allot of options like, required, silent step, executing SQL stored proc, that can return html. It is basically 1 generic form with an input box, and each controller/view output some basic html (partial view). It is C# intensive, but UI is very slim, it is SQL intensive in reagrds to allowing people to configure a step with a stored proc.